# SQLite: Primary keys not showing up

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I am beginning with SQL and started with SQLite.

I created a database and 2 tables: Employees and Managers. 
[image: Creating Managers table]

[image: Create Employees table and populate Managers and Employees table]

I then decided to check my work by looking at the schema and then displaying the contents of both tables.

[image: Check schema and display all content in Managers table]
[image: Check schema again and display all content in Employees table + separate query for just ID(Primary Key)]

What I fail to understand is why the primary keys in both tables aren't showing up when I check all of the content in the tables. The keys appear blank for the managers table even when I make the query to check the ID's specifically (image 4).

What is going on? I created a similar table for practice and the primary keys were automatically populated for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use the form `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` explicitly - `INT PRIMARY KEY` is not sufficient. (See "ROWIDs and the INTEGER PRIMARY KEY" in [the SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html).)